# Javascript Closure compiler -Exporting global variables

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

My webapp is based on a common script where I define the common functions and a global variable and dynamically loaded scripts that process those. So far, the only way I found to export the global variable is to replace any occurrence by `window["myGlobalVar"]` but I find it very ugly. Is there a better way to do?

Here is an illustration

```
// commonscript.js before compilation
function incrementVariable() {window["myGlobalVar"]++;}
window["incrementVariable"] = incrementVariable;
window["myGlobalVar"] = 0;
```

and in another script

```
alert(myGlobalVar); // <= alerts 0
incrementVariable();
alert(myGlobalVar); // <= alerts 1
```

I am looking for a way to use directly `myGlobalVar` in both files because it would be more elegant. However, I would need to set `window["myGlobalVar"]` to a pointer and not a copy of the object and I am not sure how to do that on simple types.

Is it possible? Is encapsulating `myGlobalVar` in an `Object` the only other way?

Thanks a lot for your lights.

Comment: Exporting an API is always quite clumsy in Closure. In this case, it is better to make `myGlobalVar` a private obfuscated variable, and provide a `GetMyGlobalVar` function. This way, at least you reduce the instances of `window["myGlobalVar"]`everywhere in your code.

Comment: Exporting your functions can be simpler if you use a global namespace object: `window["mynamespace"] = { "incrementVariable":incrementVariable, "getMyGlobalVar":function() { return myGlobalVar }};`  Then you can do: `alert(mynamespace.getMyGlobalVar()); mynamespace.incrementVariable(); ...`

Comment: Thanks, I thought it over and I realized how inelegant it was to use global variables anyway. I will go for the getter and setter functions that offer much more guarantee compared to globals. I figured also that encapsulating in an `Object`was not so great either. I would have the same issue with the object members which names would be obfuscated. I'd still need getter and setter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## New Answer

Closure-compiler supports an `@nocollapse` annotation which prevents a property from being collapsed to a global variable. This allows the property to be mutable when exported.

`@nocollapse` does not block renaming - you still need to export a property to accomplish that.

`@nocollapse` is currently only supported when compiling from source. It will be included in the next release - that is versions **AFTER** the v20150315 release.

## Old Answer

**`@expose` is now deprecated. The compiler will warn about any usage of `@expose`**

There is a new, but so far undocumented, annoatation: @expose. This single annotation will both export a property and prevent it from being collapsed off a constructor. It sounds like the perfect fit for your situation - but it will require your variable to be a property on an object.

However, use with care. Any properties which have @expose will not be renamed and will not be removed as dead code. This makes it especially problematic for use by javascript library writers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a variable that doesn't get renamed, just create a file called for example `props.txt` with the following contents:

```
myGlobalVar:myGlobalVar
```

Then when compiling your code, add the command line argument: `--property_map_input_file props.txt`

Your variable will not be renamed and is available to all scripts as long as it's not optimized away. Also, if you don't declare it at all (so you omit `var myGlobalVar`), it won't get renamed or removed.

Comment: While the compiler tries to honor names in the property input map, it is not required to do so. Externs are the correct solution.